# How sql organizes rows in one partition

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have always observed that if I run a query (either select or update) for multiple values in the IN clause, if those rows fall in two different partitions, query takes a lol longer and CPU usage goes up by 20-30% compared to query where rows fall under one partition. If rows fall under 3 or 4 partitions, both latency and CPU goes up further. This suggests that each partition has a dedicated physical storage location on the disc. And likely that server will use one thread  per partition. But I could not find any document that explains this. Can someone please answer? Thanks

Comment: Please include the actual [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for performance questions.

Comment: FWIW, Partitioning is not meant to improve performance for DQL and DML type of queries, and the behavior you're witnessing is normal. Rather it's a tool for improving data management.

Answer (score 3):

> This suggests that each partition has a dedicated physical storage location on the disc. And likely that server will use one thread per partition. But I could not find any document that explains this.

Partitioning is documented in several places. You could start with [Partitioned tables and indexes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes).

At a high level, all tables are partitioned but some only have one partition. You can think of a partitioned table as a collection of table-like (rowset) structures. Each partition is distinguished by a partition ID.

How threads are distributed among partitions in a *parallel* query is documented in [Parallel query execution strategy for partitioned objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide#parallel-query-execution-strategy-for-partitioned-objects). In a serial execution plan accessing multiple partitions, partitions are accessed and processed one at a time by the single thread of execution.

There is a cost to switching between partitions at runtime so the query processor often takes steps to minimize the number of partition switches, often by introducing a sort on partition ID.